# Keep rows that values in a column is found in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with many column but I show relevant columns only

```
IGV_table[["Revel_Transcripts", "Ensembl"]].head(30).to_dict()
# Converted to dict so that you can use this two-column dataframe

{'Revel_Transcripts': {0: 'ENST00000438426',
  1: 'ENST00000438426',
  2: 'ENST00000438426',
  3: 'ENST00000438426',
  4: 'ENST00000438426',
  5: 'ENST00000438426',
  6: 'ENST00000438426',
  7: 'ENST00000438426',
  8: 'ENST00000438426',
  9: 'ENST00000438426',
  10: 'ENST00000438426',
  11: 'ENST00000438426',
  12: 'ENST00000438426',
  13: 'ENST00000438426',
  14: 'ENST00000438426',
  15: 'ENST00000438426',
  16: 'ENST00000438426',
  17: 'ENST00000438426',
  18: 'ENST00000438426',
  19: 'ENST00000438426',
  20: 'ENST00000438426',
  21: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  22: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  23: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  24: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  25: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  26: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  27: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  28: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560',
  29: 'ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560'},
 'Ensembl': {0: 'ENST00000318560',
  1: 'ENST00000318560',
  2: 'ENST00000318560',
  3: 'ENST00000318560',
  4: 'ENST00000318560',
  5: 'ENST00000318560',
  6: 'ENST00000318560',
  7: 'ENST00000318560',
  8: 'ENST00000318560',
  9: 'ENST00000318560',
  10: 'ENST00000318560',
  11: 'ENST00000318560',
  12: 'ENST00000318560',
  13: 'ENST00000318560',
  14: 'ENST00000318560',
  15: 'ENST00000318560',
  16: 'ENST00000318560',
  17: 'ENST00000318560',
  18: 'ENST00000318560',
  19: 'ENST00000318560',
  20: 'ENST00000318560',
  21: 'ENST00000318560',
  22: 'ENST00000318560',
  23: 'ENST00000318560',
  24: 'ENST00000318560',
  25: 'ENST00000318560',
  26: 'ENST00000318560',
  27: 'ENST00000318560',
  28: 'ENST00000318560',
  29: 'ENST00000318560'}}
```

I want to keep rows that the value in Ensembl is found in the column Revel_Transcripts. Revel_Transcripts may have one or many values separated by ";" while Ensembl column only has one value such as ENST00000318560

The expected result

```
  Revel_Transcripts          Ensembl

21  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
22  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
23  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
24  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
25  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
26  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
27  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
28  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
29  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need test membership per rows use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True`, compare by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and test if at least one value match in [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = (IGV_table['Revel_Transcripts'].str.split(';', expand=True)
                                      .eq(IGV_table['Ensembl'], axis=0)
                                      .any(axis=1))
df = IGV_table[mask]
```

Or use list comprehension for test splitted values by column `Ensembl`:

```
mask = [b in a.split(';') for a, b in 
        zip(IGV_table['Revel_Transcripts'], IGV_table['Ensembl'])]
df = IGV_table[mask]

print (df)
                  Revel_Transcripts          Ensembl
21  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
22  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
23  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
24  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
25  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
26  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
27  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
28  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
29  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
mask = (IGV_table['Revel_Transcripts'].str.split(';').explode()
            .isin(IGV_table['Ensembl']).groupby(level=0).max())
out = IGV_table[mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                  Revel_Transcripts          Ensembl
21  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
22  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
23  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
24  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
25  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
26  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
27  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
28  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
29  ENST00000438426;ENST00000318560  ENST00000318560
```